# Is it possible to filter NPM dependency contents?

Tags: filter, npm

I use NPM to manage my front-end dependencies, but I want only to download the minified versions of my dependencies. Is this possible?

Is there something like this in `package.json` to filter them?

```
{
    "name": "my-front-end-libs",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": { 
            "version" : "3.3.5",
            "filter" : {
                "/**/*.min.*" : true   <<<--- download only files accepted by the mask
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If it’s to save bandwidth, for example, that won’t really work; the packages are served as a single .tar.gz.

Comment: You'd probably be best just using a CDN or downloading Bootstrap [from the site](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) if you *really* don't want the other files, but you'll lose version tracking, so it's probably easiest just to leave it as-is.

Comment: My application is packaged in a JAR (using spring boot) and I want to reduce it size, and bootstrap isn't the only dependency, I have about 15 MB of deps